Display SKU and Categories in live search popover
I have installed Adobe live search and it works fine. But i want to do some customization on the search popup. By default it gives the product image, Name and price only. I want to display the product SKU and categories. Do you guys have any idea?

I have checked the graphQL response and can see that we are getting SKU in the response. Please help me.

Do you found place in extension from where this pop-up create? Means response comes  ?

@MagecompProductTeam Not yet, No any single article available regarding the customization. When i enter the keywords in search box, I have all the information about the product like name, SKU, small image, price etc.. But No idea how to customize popover. Check this screenshot for response, https://ibb.co/n38j8VN

Have you check those extension files?

I am checking since last four hours, Could not able to find. Do you any idea? If yes, Just provide me the file path. I can debug that.

Without extension files how we get idea?

check this zip file, There are packages of the livesearch modules.
https://easyupload.io/45jqj2

Your answer could be here https://livesearch-autocomplete.magento-ds.com/v1/LiveSearchAutocomplete.js
Maybe replace this Called JS by your custom JS and de-minify it and debug it

Yes, It comes from third party..Let me debug
